# ApolloGraphQL: cannot find schema.json. Please specify it explicitely.Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, graphql

**I am Using  Apolloclient library in Android studio**

I have downloaded schema and pasted in main/graphql/com/example/asdf/schema.json

written query and path of the query file is ......./asdf/Xyz.graphql

After build i am getting the below error

ApolloGraphQL: cannot find schema.json. Please specify it explicitely. Looked under:
C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\ApolloClient\app\src\main\graphql

gradle dependency i used

implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.2.0'

apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.apollo'

classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:2.2.0"

Answer (score 1):

An introspection schema should have *a __schema.types* object which is not present in the json so it looks like it's missing some information. See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apollographql/apollo-android-tutorial/main/app/src/main/graphql/com/example/rocketreserver/schema.json

If introspection is enabled on your endpoint, you can download a schema with the command below:

```
./gradlew downloadApolloSchema
--endpoint=https://***/graphql
--schema=app/src/main/graphql/com/example/schema.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (I have checked this working fine) -

> Make sure everything is in single line

```
./gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint=https://***/graphql --schema=app/src/main/graphql/com/example/schema.graphqls
```

you can use **.json** or **.graphqls** accordingly